# How do I store a user data for a FB application?

Tags: facebook, flash

Say, I wrote a flash game for the Facebook and I want the user to be able to view his playing history (dates, points, highscores...). Do I necessarily have to build my own database for that? Are there any other options? I mean, ANY?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will provide some general statistics about your app (like the number of views), but if you want something as specific as points and high-score statistics, you will have to use your own database.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your app publishing scores to Facebook, and also read them back from the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/scores/